# How i can write code for ignoring undetected faces and save frames with detected faces in a new file?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, dlib

how are you all?
I am doing a project which is related to face detection. I am using dlib model for face detection. I have applied the dlib face detection model on a video clip and it is working perfectly fine. After detecting faces from a video clip I saved every frame in a new folder. Then now I am trying to align every frame with the face. The issue I am facing is that there very few frames in which dlib is not detecting the faces because of that I am getting this error
(**File "align_images.py", line 22, in 
images = dlib.get_face_chips(img, faces, size=180)
RuntimeError: No face were specified in the faces array.**)

I have checked the output of the detector and it is not detecting any faces in the frame. I want to know how to ignore the undetected frames and save the rest in a new folder.
This is my code for aligning faces.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import dlib
import sys
import tkinter

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
sp = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat")

# img = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(".frames_copy/*.jpg")]
img = cv.imread("./frames_copy/0054.jpg")

dets = detector(img, 1)

faces = dlib.full_object_detections()
for detection in dets:
    faces.append(sp(img, detection))

window = dlib.image_window()

images = dlib.get_face_chips(img, faces, size=180)

for image in images:
    window.set_image(image)
    dlib.hit_enter_to_continue()
```

Comment: What does `dets` return if no face is detected? Use the output as a condition to determine whether to pass it for face alignment or not.

Comment: This is the output of dets when no face is detected "rectangles[]" and this is the output of dets when face is detected "rectangles[[(5, -11) (79, 72)]]"

Comment: check if it's empty then skip to the next image

Comment: Yes i know i want to skip for the next image but i don't know how to write the code for this. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import dlib
import sys
import tkinter
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
sp = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat")

for f in glob.glob("face_align_samples/*"):
    os.remove(f)

# img = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(".frames_copy/*.jpg")]
# img = cv.imread("./frames_copy/0054.jpg")

aligned_faces = 0
missed_faces = 0

for index, fname in enumerate(tqdm(os.listdir('frames_copy'))):
    img = cv.imread(os.path.join("frames_copy", fname))

    dets = detector(img, 1)

    faces = dlib.full_object_detections()
    for detection in dets:
        faces.append(sp(img, detection))

    # window = dlib.image_window()

        images = dlib.get_face_chips(img, faces, size=180)
        for image in images:
            aligned_faces += 1
            cv.imwrite(os.path.join('face_align_samples', f'aligned_{str(index).zfill(5)}.png'), image)

        missed_faces += 1
        print(f'No faces were specified in the faces array for image: {fname}')
        continue

print(f'Faces aligned: {aligned_faces}\nFaces missed: {missed_faces}')
```